# Escaping Curly Braces in AS3's XML variable

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am trying to create a XML variable but I need to include a `{` and `}` in it.

```
public class MyClass {

    private var simple:XML = 
        <config>
            <url>{PROTOCOL}://{SERVER}/{FOLDER}/</url>
        </config>


    ...

}
```

Flex is trying to find a variable named `PROTOCOL`, `SERVER` and `FOLDER`.  I need to prevent this by escaping the curly brackets.

**Question:** How can I escape curly braces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a couple of thoughts:

- You can place the entire thing in a String and then cast the String (see [here](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/05/15/multi-line-strings-in-actionscript-3/) for getting a multi-line String)
- You can use replace the `{` with `&#123;` *(replacing `}` with `&#125;` is optional)*.
- Add the node in afterwards (sucks, but technically it is an option)

Comment: +1 for knowing the HTML Entity for the curly bracket.  Do you just "know that"?  Or did you have to look it up?  If you looked it up?  How/where?

Comment: (All of these assume that Flextras's suggestions don't work. Those are a good deal more obvious, mine are "Well, the obvious has failed, let's hack it")

Comment: @Flextras I'd love to claim I knew that, I'm just faster at finding my Ascii table than you are.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Works well.  Will accept your answer tomorrow.  I just want to leave it open overnight in hope that someone will suggest something more beautiful.  Changing all of the `{` in my code to ASCII makes my code much less readable.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude Yea... sometimes AS doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

I would assign the text to a string then bind that string inside the XML - avoids having to escape everything.

```
public class MyClass {

    private var simple:XML = null;

    public function MyClass()
    {
        super();

        var s:String = "{PROTOCOL}://{SERVER}/{FOLDER}/";
        simple = <config>
            <url>{s}</url>
        </config>;
    }

    ...

}
```

If you have to have a lot of text that requires escaping then you might need to look into creating the XML instance from a string as suggested by cwallenpoole or creating a function that will bind the string for a particular element and then appending it to the appropriate parent element.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect if you use a CDATA declaration, this should compile w/o problems.  That is the same way MXML allows "non-standard XML" inside a Script tag:

```
private var simple:XML = 
    <config>
        <url><![CDATA[{PROTOCOL}://{SERVER}/{FOLDER}/]]></url>
    </config>
```

There doesn't seem to be a standard HTML Entity code for the curly bracket; but based on @cwallenpoole  answer, you could create it using the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/).  { for the open bracket and } for the close bracket:

```
private var simple:XML = 
    <config>
        <url>&#123;PROTOCOL&#125;://&#123;SERVER&#125;/&#123;FOLDER&#125;</url>
    </config>
```

Comment: I think that your first solution is not good since the CDATA stays in the XML and changes it's structure.  This is bad since normally in xml the `{` char is allowed.  *It is only disallowed in as3 xml*.  Your second solution flat out does not work.  Third solution works.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude I removed the incorrect suggestion from my answer.  Is that the reason it got a downvote?  As best I understand it, don't both of these solutions change the XML?  Why are you claiming the first apparoch bad; but the second one good?

Answer (score 0):

You can also escape the **{} w/** a backslash.  For example, **{}** are used in regular expressions, but also denote binding when using RegExpValidator.

```
<mx:RegExpValidator id="regExpValidator"
                    expression="[A-Za-z0-9]\{2\}[0-9]\{1,4\}"
                    flags="gi"
                    required="true" />
```

This lets **{2}** flow through to the expression instead of evaluating to 2.